# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs' when using geopandas

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

I am getting below error when using geopandas and shapely

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Below is the code:

```
#geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(complete_major_accidents['longitude'], complete_major_accidents['latitude'])]
#crs='none'
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(complete_nonmajor_accidents.longitude, complete_nonmajor_accidents.latitude)
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
#geometries = world['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.wkt).values
#print(geometries)
#print(tuple(geometry))
gdf = GeoDataFrame(complete_major_accidents,  geometry)
gdf


ax = world[world['name'] == 'United Kingdom'].plot(figsize=(15, 15))
#print(type(ax))
gdf.plot(ax = ax, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15, edgecolor='black')
#gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(15, 15)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_330/1106976374.py in <module>
     12 ax = world[world['name'] == 'United Kingdom'].plot(figsize=(15, 15))
     13 #print(type(ax))
---> 14 gdf.plot(ax = ax, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15, edgecolor='black')
     15 #gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(15, 15)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    961         kind = kwargs.pop("kind", "geo")
    962         if kind == "geo":
--> 963             return plot_dataframe(data, *args, **kwargs)
    964         if kind in self._pandas_kinds:
    965             # Access pandas plots

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py in plot_dataframe(df, column, cmap, color, ax, cax, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, markersize, figsize, legend_kwds, categories, classification_kwds, missing_kwds, aspect, **style_kwds)
    674 
    675     if aspect == "auto":
--> 676         if df.crs and df.crs.is_geographic:
    677             bounds = df.total_bounds
    678             y_coord = np.mean([bounds[1], bounds[3]])

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5573         ):
   5574             return self[name]
-> 5575         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5576 
   5577     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Comment: can you always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors? they include tons of important debugging info, such as exactly where the error was caused and how. Check out the [ask] guide for more guidance. thanks!

Comment: also - what's going on here? `gdf.plot(ax = ax.plot(...))`? and can you indent your code correctly? whitespace is really important in python - it's hard enough for us to read someone else's code when it's [formatted](/help/formatting) *correctly* :)

Comment: I have formatted the code.

Comment: the code in the traceback is different from the code in your example. can you make sure that the code runs straight through and that you post the exact code you ran to generate the error?

Comment: but more generally, you're calling plotting functions inside other plotting functions. why are you doing this? `gdf.plot(ax = ax.plot(...))`? what are you trying to do here? what happens if you just do `gdf.plot("column name", **plotting_kwargs)`, e.g. `gdf.plot(marker='o', color='red', markersize=15, 
              edgecolor='black', ax=ax)`?

Comment: also - don't do this: `geometries = world['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.wkt).values`. you're turning all your geometries into strings. walk through your code line by line and see if you're doing what you expect - since we can't run this code (we don't have your data and you don't define all variables) we can't really help you debug this any futher, but I'd take a step back and take another look at each line to make sure it's good to go.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for your response. I have already tried the code you have suggested. Updated the latest code and error stack but still same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am finally able to resolve it by changing this below piece of code

```
gdf = GeoDataFrame(complete_major_accidents,  geometry)
```

to

```
gdf = GeoDataFrame(complete_nonmajor_accidents,  geometry = geometry)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after updating Geopandas from an older version. Following fix did the trick.

`self.ax = gpd.GeoDataFrame().plot(figsize=(18, 12))`

to

`self.ax = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[]).plot(figsize=(18, 12))`

Comment: Note: `list` obvs cannot be empty